# fail to read TCP socket in c# with readline()

Tags: c#, networking, c#-4.0, tcp, client-server

i make a simple TCP client/server in C# and i have the problem. When i test my code with telnet, the server is reading the socket fine and wrote the result. But when my client is writting a sentence on the socket, the server is block at the readLine function.

Here you have my client :

```
 public Boolean initConnection(String ip)
        {
            try
            {
              this.client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 40000);
              this.output = this.client.GetStream();
              this.reader = new StreamReader(this.output, Encoding.UTF8);
              this.writer = new StreamWriter(this.output, Encoding.UTF8);
              writer.Write("one sentence");
              return (true);
            }
          catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return (false);
            }
        }
```

and here you have my server :

```
class SNetwork
    {
        private Thread Tread;
        private TcpListener server;
        private TcpClient client;
        private StreamReader reader;
        private StreamWriter writer;
        private NetworkStream output;
        private State state;

        public void initReading()
        {
            this.server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 40000);
            output = client.GetStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(output, Encoding.UTF8);
            writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8);
            this.Tread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.read)); // this.Tread is a thread
            this.Tread.Start();
        }

   private void read()
        {
            try
            {
                while (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
                {
                    String result;

                    if (this.client.Client.Poll(10, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                    {
                        this.state = State.Closed;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (result != null && result.Length > 0)
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

Anyone can help me plz ? i don't find a solution

Comment: Try with `writer.WriteLine("one sentence");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
writer.Write("one sentence");
```

isn't writing a line terminator - so your server code doesn't know that you've finished the line. Change it to `WriteLine` (and flush the writer) it should be okay.

You always need to bear in mind that TCP/IP is a *stream-based* protocol - you can't expect the server to receive the data with as many `Read` calls as you issued `Write` calls, and if you're going for a line-terminated protocol on top, you need to make sure you terminate your lines.

(As a separate matter, it would be a good idea to follow .NET naming conventions...)